# Android AutocompleteTextView fill in when one option left

Tags: android, autocomplete

I am trying to make an AutoCompleteTextView that automatically fills in the autocomplete when there is only 1 option left in the filtered list.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

public class InstantAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteTextView {

private final static String TAG = "InstantAutoComplete";
public InstantAutoComplete(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public InstantAutoComplete(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);

}

@Override
protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
    Log.i(TAG, "REPLACING TEXT");
    super.replaceText(text);

}

@Override
public CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object obj) {
    //This needs to return a Spanned object
    return new SpannableString(super.convertSelectionToString(obj));
}

@Override
public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Count: " + count);
    super.onFilterComplete(count);
    if(count == 1) {
        clearListSelection();
        Log.i(TAG, "Is showing: " + isPopupShowing());
        setListSelection(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "Selected: "+getListSelection());
        performCompletion();
    }
}
}
```

So far I've figured out that I can check if there's only 1 item left in the dropdown in the `onFilterComplete`. However Beyond that, I'm stuck. For some reason, `setListSelection` isn't doing anything. If it were, I could use that to set the selected item, and then `performCompetion` should run as as usual. Besides that, I'm not sure that setListSelection is relative to the filtered list or to the original, longer list; but that's the next problem to solve.

So, any help on why `setListSelection` is not working, or on how to solve this problem in general is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`setListSelection` didn't work for me also.

I looked into the `AutoCompleteTextView` source code and found that a dropdown selection could be invoked by calling
`onCommitCompletion(new CompletionInfo(0, index, null));`

Hopefully this helps someone looking for a solution.

Comment: you have to call `showDropDown();` before invoking that `onCommitCompletion ` otherwise it wont work, as the framework check if the popupwindow is open nor not